# Generate only $ref in JSON.NET JsonSchemaGenerator?

Tags: json.net

I have a goal of automating converting some of my .NET model classes into Java classes.  The current method I am attempting is to use JSON.NET to generate a JSON Schema and then use jsonschema2pojo to produce the Java classes.  I have a .NET backend and .NET, Android, and iOS clients.  This particular piece is for the Android client to consume JSON RESTful resources from the .NET server.

My specific question is:

Is there a way to have JSON.NET's JsonSchemaGenerator not recurse into nested classes but instead to always specify a $ref? I'm not seeing any options for JsonSchemaGenerator and the JsonProperty attribute doesn't seem to contain anything that would help. I would like to have a schema file for each class and no duplicate definitions of a class when it's nested within another class.   jsonschema2pojo seems to work well with a directory full of schema files with each file having the name of the class.